# Looking for a webcomic from keenspace, with a demon, an angel, aliens, and all kinds of magic and conspiracies

Tags: story-identification, horror, webcomics

- The demon is initially kept in a bottle.
- The angel is actually much more and has a history going back to before history.
- The human loses his soul and get some magic chains.
- There are a pair of bounty hunters/men in black types - one is a skeleton with a squid on its head, the other is a corpse with a hook hand.
  There are grey aliens, fairies, all kinds of monsters, a creepy smiling Goddess.

There are also occasional out of story comics, one advising monsters to stop attacking high school and colleges to avoid meddling kids, that vampires should change things up and become snipers, and if all else fails yell "hastur, hastur, hastur!" and run like hell, and one with a Mecha-Cthulhu.

It stopped making new comics like two decades ago and I can't remember the name.

Comment: "anioł" czy "kąt"?

Comment: [Keenspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keenspot)?